# Cypress - finding multiple elements with the same name

Tags: arrays, element, cypress

Ok. Being naive, I though I could just jus cy.get('#selector').eq(index) to access specific elements withing an array of elemenets. Also, the examples I've been looking at, implies that the get() method will indeed return either one or an array of elements. However, I cannot get this to work with the following code:

```
<div aria-labelledby="accordion-1-tittel" class="hb-accordion-body" id="accordion-1-body" role="tabpanel">
 <app-boliginformasjon-etasje data-e2e-selector="floor" _nghost-pkr-c10="">
  <div _ngcontent-pkr-c10="" class="hb-animation--appear">
   <div _ngcontent-pkr-c10="" class="hb-layoutKontainer egot-etasje-th">
    <div _ngcontent-pkr-c10="" class="hb-egot--floor-title" translate=""> Etasje <!---->
     <span _ngcontent-pkr-c10="" data-e2e-selector="floor-number">H02</span>
      ...
 <app-boliginformasjon-etasje data-e2e-selector="floor" _nghost-pkr-c10="">
  <div _ngcontent-pkr-c10="" class="hb-animation--appear">
   <div _ngcontent-pkr-c10="" class="hb-layoutKontainer egot-etasje-th">
    <div _ngcontent-pkr-c10="" class="hb-egot--floor-title" translate=""> Etasje <!---->
     <span _ngcontent-pkr-c10="" data-e2e-selector="floor-number">H03</span><!---->
```

The elements I'm looking for here are the <span data-e2e-selector="floor-number". Ideally, I'd just want to do something like

```
cy.get('[data-e2e-selector=floor-number]').should('contain', 'H03');
```

to check the whole array for a specific value. But It's also acceptable to do something like

```
cy.get('[data-e2e-selector=floor-number]').eq(1).should('contain', 'H03')
```

However, the element returned contains only the first element, containting the 'H02' value. If I try accessing index 1 with eq(1), it doesn't exist:

```
Timed out retrying: Expected to find element: 1, but never found it. Queried from element: <span>
```

So, apparently only the first data-e2e-selector="floor-number" element is found.

Ideas?

Comment: What about some double-quotes in the selector `cy.get('[data-e2e-selector="floor-number"]')`?

Comment: See also [.should()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/should.html#Yields) ***some chainers change the subject***. In your example I'd expect multiple `cy.get('[data-e2e-selector=floor-number]')` to be filtered down to 1 element by `.should('contain', 'H03')`.

Answer (score 1):

I had issue like this:
Two buttons with the same names -> `data-cy="new-alert-button"`. I would like to catch the second one. Then I start to compare them in google inspector tool. They were almost the same but, one of them had:

```
class="pds-c-button pds-c-button_button pds-c-button_default pds-c-button_light"
```

and second had:

```
class="pds-c-button pds-c-button_button pds-c-button_default pds-c-button_primary".
```

So I decide to catch it by class `pds-c-button_primary` like this:

```
cy.get(".pds-c-button_primary").contains("Submit").click()
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to try out `within` command.
Below is just an example from my tests:

```
                cy.get('#something')
                .within(() => {
                    cy.findByText(randomDayNumber - 2).click();
                });
```

Docs: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/within